# Show that there is a one to one correspondence between the set of all parallel translations and the set of all vectors in space

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I am unsure as to how I can correctly answer this question: Show that there is a one to one correspondence between the set of all parallel translations and the set of all vectors in space

Comment: They ask you to pair up vectors and translations. They want you to do it the way pairing up normally works in the real world: each vector gets paired up with some translation, each translation gets paired up with some vector, and in addition, two different vectors won't be paired with the same translation and two different translations won't be paired with the same vector, This is what "a one to one correspondence" means (not to be confused with what one-to-one may otherwise mean, which would allow some elements to go unpaired)

Answer (score 0):

You can say that any vector $v$ defines a parallel translation via $x \mapsto x +v$. Conversely, choose an arbitrary parallel translation according to your favourite definition and show that it corresponds to $x \mapsto x +w$ for some vector $w$, this gives you the inverse of the one-to-one correspondence that you are looking for.

Hope this helps.